# How to merge data frames selecting a field from the 2nd dataframe based on order of dates in first dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes, one with company identifiers and 12 months for each company (all 12 months are sequential but there is a different sequence of months for each company), and a larger dataframe with company identifiers, all possible months and 12 different revenue fields for each month and company combination.

I want to merge these so that I have a dataframe with company identifiers and 12 dates for each company but only one revenue field for each company and date combination.  The revenue field I want to include depends on the order of the month field in the first dataframe - I hope the example below explains this.

I have tried just merging the dataframes but then I get 12 revenue amounts for each company and month combination.

I have given an example below using just 2 months for each company as that is hopefully enough to show what I would like to do (I use lubridate to create the dates in this example).

```
companies <- data.frame(
  Name   = c( rep("Company1",2), rep("Company2",2)),
  Month = c(ymd("2016-09-01"),
            ymd("2016-10-01"),
            ymd("2017-12-01"),
            ymd("2018-01-01")
            )
)

revenues <- data.frame(
  Name   = c( rep("Company1",5), rep("Company2",5)),
  Month = c(
    rep(
      c(
        ymd("2016-09-01"),
        ymd("2016-10-01"),
        ymd("2016-11-01"),
        ymd("2017-12-01"),
        ymd("2018-01-01")
      ), 2)
  ),
  RollingRev1 = c(1000, 850, 900, 950, 875, 2350, 1900, 2200, 2150, 2400),
  RollingRev2 = c(1700, 1850, 1750, 1850, 1825, 4500, 4250, 4100, 4350, 4550)
)
```

So these are my starting dataframes:

```
companies
      Name      Month
1 Company1 2016-09-01
2 Company1 2016-10-01
3 Company2 2017-12-01
4 Company2 2018-01-01

revenues
       Name      Month RollingRev1 RollingRev2
1  Company1 2016-09-01        1000        1700
2  Company1 2016-10-01         850        1850
3  Company1 2016-11-01         900        1750
4  Company1 2017-12-01         950        1850
5  Company1 2018-01-01         875        1825
6  Company2 2016-09-01        2350        4500
7  Company2 2016-10-01        1900        4250
8  Company2 2016-11-01        2200        4100
9  Company2 2017-12-01        2150        4350
10 Company2 2018-01-01        2400        4550
```

I want to end with the following dataframe

```
      Name      Month Revenue
1 Company1 2016-09-01    1000 [this is RollingRev1 as it is the 1st month]
2 Company1 2016-10-01    1850 [this is RollingRev2 as it is the 2nd month]
3 Company2 2017-12-01    2150 [this is RollingRev1 as it is the 1st month]
4 Company2 2018-01-01    4550 [this is RollingRev2 as it is the 2nd month]
```

All the other months and revenue fields are ignored.  Really the critical thing is the start month for each company as that drives the series of months and the selected revenue fields for each month but I don't know how to use that fact to combine the dataframes properly.

Comment: Do the `RollingRev` columns follow the same pattern thoughout?

Comment: Yes, they are actually cumulative revenue figures.  I do have the individual monthly figures so I was thinking it may be easier to join a dataframe with the individual monthly figures and then create a cumulative revenue field - but not sure of the easiest way to do that.

Comment: Oh no - I just realised that is a much easier approach - join the company dataframe with the monthly revenue figures and do a groupby, arrange and cumsum.  I am embarrassed that I did not see that at the outset - too focussed on working with the datasets I was given I guess.

Comment: I would suggest pivoting the tables to a long format in the future in the case of a similiar scenario. Much easier that way.